# Spring Cloud Config Client - Java Configuration HashMap or properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

Im newbie in MicroServicies, euereka and spring...

I want to start my Eureka client, getting the values from a HashMap that I created before starting the application in which the cloud information is.

```
HashMap config = new HashMap ();
config.put ("spring_cloud_config_enabled", "true");
config.put ("spring_application_name", "MicroService");
config.put ("spring_profiles_active", "default");
config.put ("spring_cloud_config_uri", "http://myHost:8888");
```

If it were empty, access the bootstrap.properties information.

Does anyone know how could i do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Following is the order of loading properties in spring application:

1. Bootstrap.properties/yaml
2. Local application.properties/yaml
3. Command Line Over-rides
4. Cloud Config application/profile based properties

Load/Over-ride happens in above format as observed. Hence you can decide fallback logic based on your requirement.

Externalized loading is summarized at following [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Adding extract from there

> 1. Devtools global settings properties on your home directory (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
> 2. @TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
> 3. @SpringBootTest#properties annotation attribute on your tests.
> 4. Command line arguments.
> 5. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> 6. ServletConfig init parameters.
> 7. ServletContext init parameters.
> 8. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
> 9. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> 10. OS environment variables.
> 11. A RandomValuePropertySource that has properties only in random.*.
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 16. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
> 17. Default properties (specified by setting SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).

Comment: I'm not sure if we've understood each other. Probably i dont understand you...  I used this ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment() (Override) to get info from my Cloud, like : [PropertySource [name=file:/root/Cloud/cloud-configuration/testService/default/application.yml] with resouces eureka client info like port or uri... Where I should use it to start my client.

Comment: If possible can you host your snippet on sample repo, so that i can have a look at your current approach and offer better insights ?